# Pyplot creating chart as 1 continuous line instead of multiple individual lines

Tags: python, matplotlib

Plotting a dataframe results in 1 line instead of 1 line per iteration of a dataframe of values.

Instead on multiple individual lines that trace positioning from a dataframe, I get 1 line which connects the end of one iteration to the start of the next and I'm not sure why.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,6))
lane2 = trajec.loc[trajec.Lane_ID == 2].sort_values(by=['Vehicle_ID', 'Frame_ID']).loc[slice(None), slice(0, 1500),:]
for id in lane2.index.get_level_values(0).unique(): # gets vehicle Ids
    yaxis = lane2['ewm_y'].loc[slice(id)]
    xaxis = yaxis.index.get_level_values(1)
    plt.plot(xaxis, yaxis)
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

As you can see we are getting a convoluted graph with each iteration being connected to the last plt.plot(x,y) call.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the problem is in the xaxis and yaxis values. Specifically, I think the data is the same in each iteration and it simply overwrites the same (long) plot line each time. The fact that there is only one color in the plot is a clue.

This code demonstrates that plt does the right thing when plotting several plot lines in a single figure:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

random.seed(1)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
xvals = range(6)
yvals = [x+random.random() for x in xvals]
for i in range(5):
    plt.plot(xvals, yvals)
    xvals = [x+1 for x in xvals]
plt.savefig('lines.png')
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I agree with you about somehow recharting the same data as it would explain the color, but the dataset is a multiindex dataframe with the vehicle id number and a frame id. The loop iteration pulls out the inner data associated with just the y position ('ewm_y') for each vehicle at each frame. The plot call should therefore plot each trajectory individually, no?

Comment: Also, if I remove the loop and plot same info manually, it works perfectly fine....

Comment: My issue was using the slice inside the .loc method. If I put only id inside the loc it works. I don't know exactly why this happens but its fixed

Comment: Good to know that you solved the problem.